# Issue in components communication via a shared service

Tags: angular, typescript, service

**Code for Service:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  private messageSource= new BehaviorSubject <string> ("This is the default message.");
  currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();

  changeMessage(message: string){
    this.messageSource.next(message);
  }

  constructor() { }

}
```

**Code for Parent:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {DataService} from '../data.service';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-parent',
      template: `{{message}}`,
      styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css'],

    })
    export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

      message: string;

      constructor(private data: DataService) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.data.currentMessage.subscribe (message => this.message = message);

    }
```

**Code for Sibling:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from "../data.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sibling',
  template:`
        {{message}}
        <button (click)="newMessage()">Click Me</button>
  ` ,
  styleUrls: ['./sibling.component.css'],
  providers: [DataService]
})
export class SiblingComponent implements OnInit {

  message: string;

  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.currentMessage.subscribe( message => this.message = message);

  }

  newMessage(){
    this.data.changeMessage("This is a message from sibling.");
  }
}
```

**Code for app.component.html:**

```
<app-parent></app-parent>
<br>
<app-sibling></app-sibling>
```

**Code for NgModule:**

```
@NgModule({   declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ParentComponent,
    SiblingComponent,
    DataService   ]
```

By clicking on the button *Click Me* in *Sibling*, the `message` variable in both *Parent* and *Sibling* has to change to *This is a message from sibling* . However, this does not happen for *Parent* and still *This is the default message* is rendered to *app.component.html*.
Could you please help me in finding out the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you provide service on a component level it means that you create new instance of this service. If you want your components share one instance of service you should provide it on one level higher or on a module.

I suspect you provided the same service on module so try removing:

```
providers: [DataService]
```

from `SiblingComponent` metadata.

Your `@NgModule` could look like:

```
@NgModule({   
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    DataService
  ]
```

**[ng-run demo](https://ng-run.com/edit/r8vdkIvEGn3bGP8Z7jQp)**

See also

- https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#ngmodule-or-component

Comment: By removing it from Sibling, I won't be able to use it in its constructor and I get compile time error.

Comment: Did you provide it on @NgModule?

Comment: Yes. I have even added the NgModule to my post

Comment: You should add `DataService`  to `providers` array not `declarations`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove providers: [DataService] from app-sibling component

when using service in angular u have two ways ,

1.using providers within component - this approach will create a new instance of the service in this component

2.using providers within NgModule- this approach will create a single tone instance shared between all components and u can use it by injecting the service in the component constructor 
In you case u create two instance one global and another one in sibling component ,so parent and sibling are not in the same level u just need to add it one time in NgModule

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ParentComponent } from './parent/parent.component';
import { SiblingComponent } from './sibling/sibling.component';
import { DataService } from './data.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ParentComponent,
    SiblingComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [DataService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```